# Navigating from cell within UIHostingController to a SwiftUI View

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

I am using this [great resource](https://defagos.github.io/swiftui_collection_part2/#cell-layout) to implement a UICollectionView within SwiftUI. Everything works great and the performance is much better compared to SwiftUI's native LazyVGrid.

I want to navigate from an item in the cell, which is essentially a thumbnail, to a larger version of the photo, which is straightforward in SwiftUI.

```
CollectionView(rows: rows) { sectionIndex, layoutEnvironment in
            let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1))
            let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
            
            let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1/2))
            let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
            
            let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
            section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .continuous
            return section
        } cell: { indexPath, photo in
            GeometryReader { geoReader in
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: ImageDetailView(photo: photo)) {
                    photo.imageDownsampled(pointSize: geoReader.size)
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                }
                .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                .animation(nil)
            }
        } supplementaryView: { kind, indexPath in
            Text("Section \(indexPath.section)")
        }
```

This does not work. I believe the crux of the issue is that the cell view is placed with a UIHostingController, which doesn't know what the do with the NavigationLink.

```
    private class HostCell: UICollectionViewCell {
        private var hostController: UIHostingController<Cell>?
        
        override func prepareForReuse() {
            if let hostView = hostController?.view {
                hostView.removeFromSuperview()
            }
            hostController = nil
        }
        
        var hostedCell: Cell? {
            willSet {
                guard let view = newValue else { return }
                hostController = UIHostingController(rootView: view, ignoreSafeArea: true)
                if let hostView = hostController?.view {
                    hostView.frame = contentView.bounds
                    hostView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
                    contentView.addSubview(hostView)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What are my options for implementating the segue from the cell to my existing, separate SwiftUI view that displays the larger image?